Using nodemon I am facing error - ReferenceError: app is not defined
Getting ReferenceError: app is not defined.
Here is the error details- with source code
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting node server.js
D:\ebl\server\app\routes.js:4
app.get('/health', (_req, res) => {
^
ReferenceError: app is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ebl\server\app\routes.js:4:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ebl\server\app\app.js:8:9)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
Node.js v20.9.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
app.js
//app.js
require('dotenv').config('../.env')
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

app.use(require('./middleware'));
app.use(require('./routes'));
app.use(require('./error'));

module.exports = app;

routes.js
 const router = require('express').Router();

 app.get('/health', (_req, res) => {
 res.status(200).json({ message: 'success' })
 });

 module.exports = router

package.json
{
  "name": "ebl",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ebl",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "ebl",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.3.5",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  }
}


I chanage the path route '/health' to another name '/home', but error is the same

router.get('/health', ...) in routes.js

@moonwave99 your code give me a good sence, thank you


Getting ReferenceError: app is not defined.

Just change the following in routes.js.
router.get('/health', (_req, res) => {...


Your solution not works at all, thanks for your try

@jamj,sorry for that and also  thank you for bringing it into my notice. I have made a mistake that I have corrected in my post. The first comment of your post was right.
Since the route.js export router it should be router.get('..

Now your corrected code is right, thank you
